# How to determine whether the vector valued function satisfy the Lipschitz condition?

Tags: nonlinear-system, lipschitz-functions, nonlinear-analysis

Given, vector-valued function $\phi(x)=\left[ \begin{array} 
aa x_{1}^{2}/(x_{1}+b)+x_{1}x_{3}+\frac{6}{\pi}arctan(\frac{x_{1}}{b}-180)+e+c \\
x_{1}x_{3}+x_{2}x_{4}\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0 
\end{array}\right]$
where $x=[x_{i}]^{T},i=1,...,6$ and $a,b,c,e$ are known positive constants. All the $x_{i},i=1,...,6$ are bounded and positive.

Q1/ Does this $\phi(x)$ satisfies the Lipschitz nonlinearity condition locally or globally? If yes, then kindly help me with the proof.

Q2/ Calculate the Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 2):

1) Wherever the function is continuously differentiable, it is Lipschitz.

2) Lipschitz implies continuous everywhere and differentiable almost everywhere, so consider the largest subset $S$ of the domain which satisfies those two conditions. Wherever the function is differentiable in $S$, if the derivative is bounded, then it is Lipschitz.

In either case, the constant is $L = \sup\limits_{x\in S} |f'(x)|$.

These two conditions will usually allow you to determine if a function given in closed form is Lipschitz. When dealing with a vector valued function, you can just look componentwise, and make sure you're using the correct definition of differentiable for multivariable functions (not just existence of first partials).

---

These conditions will probably not help if you have a nonstandard function defined by integral, power series, or as the solution of a given equation, so it's not flawless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, I need the Lipschitz constant value in order to use it. Can you help me in calculating the Lipschitz constant?

Comment: I added the formula for the constant.

Comment: Can you provide the derivation with steps to compute the Lipschitz constant.